# Laravel - cant retrive data from ajax to controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, post, controller

I am trying to retrieve a data from ajax to controller but it seems like ajax is not passing any data.

**Meta for Token:**

```
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});    

// AJAX Call

$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "someurl",
   data: JSON.stringify({'sample': 'test'}),
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(err) {
       console.log(err);
   }
});
```

**Routes:**

```php
Route::post('/someurl', 'AdminController@updateUser');
```

**Controller:**

```php
public function updateUser() {

   $myTest = Input::all();

   return response()->json(json_encode($myTest));
}
```

I can call the controller without a problem but when i add `Input:all()`, I get a `500 server error`. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Check your server log for more details, usually when you see a 500 error you would want to do that.

Comment: check by echo $myTest or print_r $myTest if they have any value or not?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know, Input::all() works by Laravel Requests. You're not handeling a request but pure raw POST data, so Input::all() doesn't work. Try accessing it with `$myTest = $_POST['sample']` and see if that does the job. Oh and for your convenience, I'd go for the following if you're using Blade template engine:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "someurl",

   data: {
       'sample': 'test', 
        '_token' : '{{csrf_token()}}'
   },

   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
},
   error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
});
```

and leave away the ajaxsetup and csrf field